# Desktop Facebook application for Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, facebook

There is an excellent desktop Twitter application for Ubuntu. It is called Corebird. Is there any such application for Facebook?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is being used?

Comment: OP posted question on August 16th and last signed in here on August 18th so an answer to your question is unlikely.

Comment: Will definitively award the bounty , just want to wait a little bit longer to see if more answers arise :)

Answer (score 7):

There is this ([Messenger for desktop](https://messengerfordesktop.com/)):

[image]

---

There is this ([www.messenger.com](https://www.messenger.com/)):

[image: Facebook Messenger 2]

---

Also using these instructions ([facebook.com - help: Facebook Messenger for Linux ubuntu](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200236345979960)) from within Chrome you can create a webapp on any desktop (with Chrome of course) from facebook mobile page:

1. In chrome go to `m.facebook.com`
2. Go to 'hamburger menu' (three lines top right) and navigate to Tools-> Create shortcut
3. Pick if you want it in start menu (Dash in Ubuntu) and/or desktop shortcut
4. Enjoy ;)

[image: Facebook Chrome Webapp]

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to install in Trusty (14.04) or Precise (12.04), there is a desktop-facebook package available from [ppa:folke-schwinning/personal](https://launchpad.net/~folke-schwinning/+archive/ubuntu/personal)

If you'd like to try it you can install it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:folke-schwinning/personal
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install desktop-facebook
```

It doesn't appear that there has been any recent work on this package (last successful builds 4/20/14) and I don't use it so I can't speak to it's efficacy which might have changed since facebook decided to [drop support for facebook messenger for Windows](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151971041364786) but there is an old article about it [here.](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/07/fb-messenger-and-facebook-applications.html) My search hasn't come up with anything more current for Ubuntu (Although there is the [f8 app for Andrioid and IOS](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app)) it doesn't appear to be [installable on Ubuntu.](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/issues/143)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/813084/desktop-facebook-application-for-ubuntu#comment1336347_813084 so you know you didnt do this in vain.

Comment: @Videonauth :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go hardcore from the terminal (what Linux user *doesn't*?), you can use the [Facebook Client Terminal](https://github.com/kissrobber/facebook_client_terminal).

1. **Install Dependencies**: You need NodeJS, NPM, and Git installed to make this work, so do that first:

   ```
    sudo apt install npm nodejs-legacy git
   ```
2. **Go Somewhere Safe**: This project will have to sit somewhere. For this example, it will be at `~/.opt/fbct`. Decide where you want it to be, it honestly doesn't matter as long as you have write privileges.

   ```
    mkdir ~/.opt/fbct
    cd ~/.opt/fbct
   ```
3. **Clone The Repo**: Now that you have your environment set up, clone the repository:

   ```
    git clone https://github.com/kissrobber/facebook_client_terminal.git .
   ```
4. **Set Things Up**: Fortunately, setup is (relatively) easy in this case. Just move a file, really:

   ```
    mv js/config.json.example js/config.json
   ```
5. **Log In**: Again, relatively simple. You're just logging into Facebook.

   ```
    node js/run.js
   ```

   The command-line terminal will open. Type `login` to get started. In your browser, navigate to [`http://127.0.0.1:1337`](http://127.0.0.1:1337), and click the `login` link. You will be redirected to the Facebook login.
6. **Use Facebook!** You can either use Facebook from the terminal you have open in Node already, or you can use `node js/cmd.js <command>`. You can get a basic command reference from the Github page linked above.

Comment: Don't like that option, because you have to register a facebook app to be able to use this CLI, and to do so, you have to give your phone number to facebook. This is something I don't wanna do... Is there any other CLI option without having to register a facebook app ?$*

Comment: As far as I know, this is the only solution. Besides, it's not as though Facebook doesn't have way more information on you that your phone number would make any difference.