Download Facebook on Ubuntu. I get my ans . It can't be use in ubuntu
I want to download Facebook on Ubuntu. What do I need to do to install this?
The answers in Desktop Facebook application for Ubuntu are not valid in Ubuntu 24.04, or any currently supported versions.

i want to download facebook in unbuntu .Tell me can it be possible or not . I am new so i don't understand it .Beacuse it is my first time i am using ubuntu .So , i have no much knowledge about it

You can open a web browser and log into facebook. Why do you want to download facebook?

The answers in https://askubuntu.com/questions/813084/desktop-facebook-application-for-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1 don't seem to be valid. I am voting to reopen.

@ArchismanPanigrahi then post an updated answer on it, if you have one. Why reopen this one? If you want to bring more attention to outdated answers, there is an existing mechanism for that: bounties. There is a standard bounty reason: "Current answers are outdated The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes."

This question is similar to: Desktop Facebook application for Ubuntu. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@karel it's more logical to post updated answers to posts that have already high visibility in search results, as those posts will anyway show up in searches and confuse users if they don't have up-to-date answers.

Which browser are you using? With certain browsers it is possible to make a web app that will look like a separate app.

There is no need for a software download on Ubuntu. Just point your favorite browser to: www.facebook.com and login from there.
If you still insist for a download, You can try this snap. Sorry I do not have specifics on how it works:
To install facebook-webapp, simply use the following command:
sudo snap install facebook-webapp
From this Source

i use this code and download facebook in ubuntu . But it was not for use .It was like demo version . i understand now in ubuntu can't installed facebook .I need to use facebook from firefox browser .Thanks for your valuable information

@MerazulRiyad That's the normal way you use any website in any operating system, be it Ubuntu, Windows, macOS etc. You just open the website in a web browser, you don't need a specific app for any particular website.
Per-website apps are mostly mobile phones thing, but even there they're mostly unnecessary. On my Android tablet I use Facebook, Twitter, Youtube etc. etc. all from the browser, I don't have any separate apps for them (either never installed or uninstalled the preinstalled ones).
